# How to include html view files in react.js

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, react-redux

I have a web app developed in Laravel with blade.html views, I want to create a new feature which will be created in React Js and it will use some of html view files.
Now i have tried setting *"innerhtml"* and including html view files in react js but i can't access my php variables and methods.
**how can i include html view files in React Js?**

Answer (score 1):

`innerhtml` will not work for React.

Take a look at [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml).

It can be used in this way:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: 'First;<br/> Second....'}} />
```

Although, writing your views in react would be the better option if that is doable.